# I want to save list of holidays With date and day in my 1st view. How do we do that?

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to save list of holidays in my 1st view.  I have another  view (i.e, 2nd View) where am selecting the date, day and typing festival name in the textfield in that view. I want to show  that selected data in my 1st View when i click on back buttono navigation bar . How do we do that??

How to show the selected data in my 1st View?? and i want to store it on  phone memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store value festival name and selected date in NSUserDefault

Now in 1st View's view will appear which will be called when back button is presswd

if  NSUserDefault has festival name and selected date then show them